# Dents in aluminum

Tags: aluminum

I am looking at a good alloy road bike, cannondale caad12.
It is a good deal but there are some dents all the down the seatstays, not major but not nothing.
Is it safe?
Does it affect the bike?
Should I still consider buying it??
Thanks
Charlie

Comment: without photos, cannot even guess what your measure of "not nothing" is. Generally if a deal is too god be be true, it is.

Comment: Keep in mind that such abuse likely reflects upon the condition of the rest of the bike as well.

Comment: Without pictures it's hard to do anything with a question like this.

Comment: Is this the same bike with the loose cassette in your other question?  Sound like some PO has not cared for it.

Answer (score 3):

Aluminium doesn't like dents.  Steel bikes can cope with enormous dings, but on an aluminum frame the same dent would weaken the metal, and undenting it makes the weakness worse.

It may be worth acquiring as a parts donor, if the groupset/stem/bars/wheels are in reusable condition.

Ultimately it is your decision.

Comment: Being that the dents are on the seatstays, where there is far less material implying the dent involves more of the surface area of the structure, makes it a deal breaker for me.  The fact that there are numerous dents would make the situation even more potentially ominous. There is no economically--nor practical,  in my mind--feasible repair either.  I would keep your money and move on.